# Ошибка при вызове функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что надо исправить или добавить?

```
def a(self):
    self.a = "lol"

def b(self):
    print(self.a)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ```
> b() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
> ```

Comment: во-первых, здесь нет того кода, который вызывает эту ошибку. Во-вторых, добавить нужно знания об использовании функций. Еще, возможно, знаний английского языка

Comment: Это не совсем функции а методы класса. Во-первый чтобы создать методы класса нужно иметь сам класс. В вашем коде его нет, видимо в вопрос вы не весь код добавили.  Ну а ошибка означает, что вы неправильно обращаетесь к методу класса, скорее всего вы написали ```b()``` а нужно писать ```classname.b()```, где classname - имя созданного вами класса

Answer (score 1):

У функций указано по одному аргументу, однако они не заданы при вызове. Чтобы вызывать эти функции без явного указания аргумента, необходимо сделать их членами класса.

```py
class Test:
    def a(self):
        self.a = "lol"

    def b(self):
        print(self.a)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Если же вы хотели указывать поле "a" у какого-то конкретного объекта, то следует указывать его при вызове функции

```
test = object()
a(test)
b(test)
```

Comment: место создания отдельного класса можно записать просто `test = object()`

Comment: @Danis спасибо, поправил. Я думал над этим, но как-то сам не сталкивался, а смотреть специально было лень

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, это методы класса, поэтому я опишу класс `Test` с этими методами:

```
class Test:
  def a(self):
    self.a = "lol"

  def b(self):
    print(self.a)
```

Попробуем вызвать `b` как метод класса:

```
Test.b()
```

Вывод:

```
TypeError: b() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Поскольку у методов `a` и у `b` есть параметр `self`, их правильно вызывать не от класса, а от экземпляра класса, тогда параметр `self` передастся автоматически:

```
t = Test()
t.a()
t.b()
```

Вывод:

```
lol
```

Однако, в вашем коде есть ещё одна проблема, попробуем вызвать метода `a` два раза подряд:

```
t = Test()
t.a()
t.a()
```

Вывод:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Дело в том, что вас есть функция `Test.a`, однако в экземпляре этого класса вы когда делаете в методе `a` присваивание `self.a = "lol"`, вы таким образом затираете ссылку на функцию `a` строкой `lol`. Python хранит все имена вместе, ему всё-равно что это - переменная или функция. Под одним именем может быть только одна какая-то сущность, вне зависимости от того, как эта сущность используется. Так что не делайте у методов и полей класса одинаковые названия, чтобы они друг-друга не затирали.